Get Bot Service direct line key in bicep?
How do I get a Bot Service's DirectLine Key with a bicep?
I have a bicep that creates the bot service and then creates the app service.  I need to add the direct line key as an app setting value in the app service. I can't find a way to get the key from the bot resource in my bicep.
I saw some posts that indicate that I might be able to get the key with the CLI or with an http call, but that seems convoluted when I'm building everything with a bicep.  I am probably overlooking something simple?

You can retrieve the key using the listChannelWithKeys() function:
param botServiceName string

// reference to bot service
resource botService 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices@2023-09-15-preview' existing = {
  name: botServiceName
}


// reference to bot service channel
resource directLineChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2023-09-15-preview' existing = {
  parent: botService
  name: 'DirectLineChannel'
}

// DO NOT USE OUTPUT in real world
output directLine object = directLineChannel.listChannelWithKeys()

